# How to Find The Closest Date in Rows Using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-structures

I have a data case like this:

I would like to know the closest date to the given date, but it should not exceed the given date.
Here's the data:

| Date_1 | Date_2 | Date_3 | Given_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/12/2022 12:56:49 | 27/12/2022 11:22:32 | 30/12/2022 12:32:53 | 26/12/2022 13:22:39 |
| 03/12/2022 11:23:46 | 05/12/2022 13:42:12 | 07/12/2022 11:11:21 | 08/12/2022 13:15:20 |
| 15/11/2022 09:07:56 | 16/11/2022 10:37:51 | 18/11/2022 21:13:22 | 16/11/2022 13:21:23 |

And I would like to categorize them like this:
\n
\n

| Date_1 | Date_2 | Date_3 | Given_Date | Closest_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23/12/2022 12:56:49 | 27/12/2022 11:22:32 | 30/12/2022 12:32:53 | 26/12/2022 13:22:39 | Date_1 |
| 03/12/2022 11:23:46 | 05/12/2022 13:42:12 | 07/12/2022 11:11:21 | 08/12/2022 13:15:20 | Date_3 |
| 15/11/2022 09:07:56 | 16/11/2022 10:37:51 | 18/11/2022 21:13:22 | 16/11/2022 13:21:23 | Date_2 |

How could I categorize them based on the given table using python?

Comment: for the first row, the closest date is Date_2, not Date_1

Comment: thanks for the answer. the case said that it should be close but not exceed. Date_2 exceeding the given date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), get the diff to Closest_Date, filter the dates, and get the [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

df['Closest_Date'] = (df2
                      .filter(regex='^Date')
                      .rsub(df2['Given_Date'], axis=0)
                      .pipe(lambda d: d.mask(d.lt('0')))
                      .idxmin(axis=1)
                      )
```

*NB. saving the conversion to datetime in a new dataframe is only required if the original strings need to be maintained.*

output:

```
                Date_1               Date_2               Date_3  \
0  23/12/2022 12:56:49  27/12/2022 11:22:32  30/12/2022 12:32:53   
1  03/12/2022 11:23:46  05/12/2022 13:42:12  07/12/2022 11:11:21   
2  15/11/2022 09:07:56  16/11/2022 10:37:51  18/11/2022 21:13:22   

            Given_Date Closest_Date  
0  26/12/2022 13:22:39       Date_1  
1  08/12/2022 13:15:20       Date_3  
2  16/11/2022 13:21:23       Date_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), which will have the advantage of giving a NaN if no match is found:

```
df2 = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

s = (pd.merge_asof(df2['Given_Date'].reset_index().sort_values(by='Given_Date'),
                   df2.filter(regex='^Date').stack().sort_values()
                      .reset_index(name='Given_Date'),
                   left_by='index', right_by='level_0', on='Given_Date'
                   )
       .set_index('level_0')['level_1']
    )

df['Closest_Date'] = s
```

output:

```
                Date_1               Date_2               Date_3  \
0  23/12/2022 12:56:49  27/12/2022 11:22:32  30/12/2022 12:32:53   
1  03/12/2022 11:23:46  05/12/2022 13:42:12  07/12/2022 11:11:21   
2  15/11/2022 09:07:56  16/11/2022 10:37:51  18/11/2022 21:13:22   

            Given_Date Closest_Date  
0  26/12/2022 13:22:39       Date_1  
1  08/12/2022 13:15:20       Date_3  
2  16/11/2022 13:21:23       Date_2
```